# How does placement of parentheses in VB.NET affect an array (in the actual program)?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, declaration

I'm a beginner in VB (working in .NET console application) and I don't understand the difference between these two:

1. Dim **array1 as Integer( )** = New Integer( ) { }
2. Dim **array2( ) as Integer** = New Integer( ) { }

I understand that the first one declares an integer variable of an array type and the second declares an array of integer type.
But what difference does it make in the program itself?

In my materials both are used in the same way and it contains no explanation as to why use one or the other.
Is it because the program executes them the same way?

Comment: Download the [language specification](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15039), keep it handy.  Chapter 7.9 tells you they are the same, pick the syntax you prefer.  Syntax 2 is the more common choice.

Comment: The second option is what Microsoft used to recommend but they now recommend the first option. It's worth noting that you must put the parentheses on the variable if you are creating the array by specifying the upper bound.

Comment: It’s a just a code style. The first one is a C/C++ style and the second more by C#/Java style.
There is no differences.. You can use what you want, but if you take a way is better you use the same every time.

Comment: Thank you guys so much